# How can I store the result of a system command in a Perl variable?

Tags: perl, command, system

```
$ cat test.pl
my $pid = 5892;
my $not = system("top -H -p $pid -n 1 | grep myprocess | wc -l");
print "not = $not\n";
$ perl test.pl
11
not = 0
$
```

I want to capture the result i.e. `11` into a variable. How can I do that?

Comment: Also see [What's the differences between system and backticks and pipes in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/797127)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

From [Perlfaq8](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#Why-can't-I-get-the-output-of-a-command-with-system()%3f):

You're confusing the purpose of [system()](http://p3rl.org/system) and [backticks](http://p3rl.org/op#qx%2fSTRING%2f) (``). system() runs a command and returns exit status information (as a 16 bit value: the low 7 bits are the signal the process died from, if any, and the high 8 bits are the actual exit value). Backticks (``) run a command and return what it sent to STDOUT.

```
$exit_status   = system("mail-users");
$output_string = `ls`;
```

There are many ways to execute external commands from Perl. The most commons with their meanings are:

- **[system()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html)** : you want to execute a command and don't want to capture its output
- **[exec](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html)**: you don't want to return to the
  calling perl script
- **[backticks](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#qx%2fSTRING%2f)** : you want to capture the
  output of the command
- **[open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html):** you want to pipe the command (as
  input or output) to your script

Also see [How can I capture STDERR from an external command?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-can-I-capture-STDERR-from-an-external-command%3f)

Comment: Worth noting: if you want the output to be split on newlines *(which is probably the case in the example with with `ls`)*, just assign it to "array" variable. I.e. replace `$output_string = \`ls\`` with `@output_string = \`ls\``

Answer (score 16):

The easiest way is to use the ``` `` ``` feature in Perl. This will execute what is inside and return what was printed to stdout:

```
 my $pid = 5892;
 my $var = `top -H -p $pid -n 1 | grep myprocess | wc -l`;
 print "not = $var\n";
```

This should do it.

Comment: Is the $pid substitution within backtics a new feature? Can't get it to work with `v5.6.1`.

Comment: This has worked as far as I can remember.
e.g. try : `perl -e '$a="Hello"; print \`echo $a\`'`

Answer (score 10):

Try using `qx{command}` rather than backticks. To me, it's a bit better because: you can do SQL with it and not worry about escaping quotes and such. Depending on the editor and screen, my old eyes tend to miss the tiny back ticks, and it shouldn't ever have an issue with being overloaded like using angle brackets versus glob.

Comment: Great answer! Solved my problem!

Answer (score 4):

Using `backtick` or `qx` helps, thanks everybody for the answers. However, I found that if you use `backtick` or `qx`, the output contains trailing newline and I need to remove that. So I used `chomp`.

```
chomp($host = `hostname`);
chomp($domain = `domainname`);
$fqdn = $host.".".$domain;
```

More information here: 
http://irouble.blogspot.in/2011/04/perl-chomp-backticks.html

Comment: chomp really is a strange beast... i don't  get it, why $host = `hostname` ; $out = chomp($host) is not working...

Comment: `chomp` returns the number of characters it removed after it modifies your argument. You almost never care about what `chomp` returns.

Answer (score 1):

Use backticks for system commands, which helps to store their results into Perl variables.

```
my $pid = 5892;
my $not = ``top -H -p $pid -n 1 | grep myprocess | wc -l`; 
print "not = $not\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Also for eg. you can use [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run):

```perl
use IPC::Run qw(run);

my $pid = 5892;
run [qw(top -H -n 1 -p), $pid],
    '|', sub { print grep { /myprocess/ } <STDIN> },
    '|', [qw(wc -l)],
    '>', \my $out;

print $out;
```

- processes are running without bash subprocess
- can be piped to perl subs
- very similar to shell