# Is there any use in providing arguments as separate parameters to a system call using Perl?

Tags: perl

On Unix, all these three generate the same result

```
system("top -H -p $pid -n 1");             #ver1
system("top", "H", "p $pid", "n 1");       #ver2
system("top", "-H", "-p $pid", "-n 1");    #ver3
```

- What is the difference between **ver2** and **ver3**?
- Is there any reason I should use **ver2** and **ver3**, and not **ver1**?
- They do not even support piping the results, for example, are there any **ver2** and **ver3** equivalents of the following call?

  ```
  system("top -H -p $pid -n 1 | grep myprocess | wc -l");
  ```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854651/how-can-i-store-the-result-of-a-system-command-in-a-perl-variable by the same user

Comment: closevoter, this is not a duplicate. At least read the questions before marking. @PP: Did you mean to say it was a duplicate?

Comment: No, I mentioned the link because the questions are related.

Comment: I explain a lot of this in _Mastering Perl_ in the security chapter. It's all in the docs, though, too.

Comment: @brian, can you please link the relevant part of the docs? Nothing is mentioned [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html).

Comment: Well, I condensed it all into _Mastering Perl_. The rest is up to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even it looks same it is not same:

```
$ perl -e 'system("./test.pl -H -p $$ -n 1");system("./test.pl", "H", "p $$", "n 1");system("./test.pl", "-H", "-p $$", "-n 1");'
-H,-p,10497,-n,1
H,p 10497,n 1
-H,-p 10497,-n 1
$ cat ./test.pl 
#!/usr/bin/perl
$\="\n";
$,=",";
print @ARGV;
```

It is up to `top` implementation that it works same. Other applications may not work same.

Answer (score 3):

Quoth perlfunc for [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html):

> Note that argument processing varies depending on the number of arguments. If there is more than one argument 
>   in LIST, or if LIST is an array with more than one value, starts the program given by the first element of 
>   the list with arguments given by the rest of the list. If there is only one scalar argument, the argument is checked for shell metacharacters, and if there are any, the entire argument is passed to the system's command shell for parsing (this is /bin/sh -c on Unix platforms, but varies on other platforms). If there are no shell metacharacters in the argument, it is split into words and passed directly to execvp , which is more efficient.

So if `$pid` is just digits, all are equivalent.

To interpolate results of an arbitrary shell command including pipes use [qx](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#qx%2fSTRING%2f) and friends.

Answer (score 3):

As a practical reason for using LIST, sometimes your command-line arguments contain spaces or other characters that would confuse your shell.

```
system("mplayer.exe", "--volume", "75",
       q[C:/Program Files/My Music Player/Music Library/The "Music" Song.mp3]);
```

Answer (score 1):

- What is the difference between ver2 and ver3?

Just in what arguments you're passing to `top`.  I don't know of a version of `top` that will take switches without dashes like some versions of `ps` do, so you should use version 3.

- Is there any reason I should use ver2 and ver3, and not ver1?

If you pass a single string to `system` it will run it via your shell.  This means it will be shell interpreted.  Any stray spaces or shell meta characters (quotes, dollar signs, etc...) in the arguments would be interpreted and possibly mess things up.  It's also a potential security hole.

For example, if `$pid` was something like `'10; echo pwnd; echo '` then you'd run `top -H -p 10` then `echo pwnd` then `echo -n1`.

So for both safety and security, unless you need shell processing (see below) you should pass system a list.

- Are there any ver2 and ver3 equivalents which allow pipes?

No, piping and redirection is done by the shell.  You have to use something other than `system`.  You can do it with `open`, but it's a pain in the ass.  Easiest way is to use [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/module/IPC%3a%3aRun#Syntax).

```
use IPC::Run;

my $out;
run ["echo", "foo\nbar\nbaz"], "|",
    ["grep", "ba"],            "|",
    ["wc",   "-l"],
    \$out;
print $out;  # 2
```

But really if you're just grepping and counting a handful of lines, use Perl.

```
my $out;
run ["echo", "foo\nbar\nbaz"], '>', \$out;

my $count = grep { /ba/ } split /\n/, $out;
print $count;
```