# Perl: Print 5 lines above regexmatch

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to print 5 lines above "END" from a huge data file.

Can anyone please help? My file format is

```
 --   Count .    .    .     . . .   .   .   .   .   .   . . . . . . . . . . . .  -------------------------------------    ------------------------------------------- 
00000001 0000 0000 00000 2 0 01c 01d 01c 01d 01c 01d 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 00 
00000002 0001 0000 00000 2 2 019 006 019 006 019 006 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 00
00000003 0002 0000 00000 2 0 00d 007 00d 007 00d 007 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 00
00000004 0003 0000 00000 2 2 00b 009 00b 009 00b 009 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 00 
00000005 0004 0000 00000 2 2 01a 008 01a 008 01a 008 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 00
END
```

~

Comment: Can you please show the examples you refer to? We don't see any operator `[$#i]` here. The construct `$#i` is the index of the last element of an array `@i`, e.g. `@i = (100, 200, 300);` yields `$#i == 2`.

Comment: For example : http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=983672  "$#lines"

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please edit your question to include a complete minimal code example and small test file that can be used to help you solve your issue. Please include the information you obtained and the expected results. Otherwise we're just guessing. Thanks

Comment: Sorry. I feel the question is more clear now

Comment: Please include the code you have tried

Comment: A regex alternative: https://regex101.com/r/jF3jN7/1

Answer (score 2):

Just use grep:

```
grep END file -B 5
```

Alternatively, you can use either of the following Perl one-liners:

```
perl -ne'print @a if /^END$/; push @a, $_; shift(@a) if @a>5;' file
```

or

```
perl -ne'push @a, $_; print @a if /^END$/; shift(@a) if @a>5;' file
```

The second prints the matching line, which the first one does not.

Comment: I need to use this in my script its a smart part then I need to perform operation on that. Can you please suggest in the form of perl script

Comment: If this has to be in perl then show what you have tried so far.

Comment: You can also run it inside a script using backticks to store the output in a variable. More info that might be helpful in this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854651/how-can-i-store-the-result-of-a-system-command-in-a-perl-variable

Answer (score 1):

Just keep the last 5 lines you've read in memory.

```
my $found = 0;
my @buf;
while (<>) {
   if (/^END$/) {
       $found = 1;
       last;
   }

   push(@buf, $_);
   shift(@buf) if @buf > 5;
}

print(@buf) if $found;
```