# How can I run a shell command in perl scipt and return the result to a variable in my perl script(without returning the result to the unix)

Tags: perl, unix, command

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [How can I store Perl's system function output to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415954/how-can-i-store-perls-system-function-output-to-a-variable)

I have tried to run a shell command in my Perl script.  An example is like below:

```
system ("ls -al");
```

The result is well printed on Unix.

Is there a way to return the result to `$string` in my Perl script instead of returning the result on Unix?

I do not want the result to be printed on my Unix.

Comment: This is well covered in the Perl manpage for back tick operator at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#%60STRING%60

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the backticks:

```
$string = `ls -al`;
```

The 'qx' delimiter is a synonym for this:

```
$string = qx{ls -al};
```

This is documented [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) in the [perlop man page](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html).

Alternately, you can use `open` with '|' like so:

```
open my $filehandle, "ls -al|" or die "Open failed!\n";
while(<$filehandle>) {do_something($_);}
close $filehandle;
```

In this case, you're opening a filehandle to a pipe attached to the command's output (basically treating the output as a file). This is handy if the command takes a long time or produces more output than you want to store in memory at a time. This is documented in the [Perl open manual](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html).

Comment: $var = qx(ls -l 2>&1) will also give you the errors in $var....by default qx does not capture stderr. You should also examine the value of $@, which is the exit code of the program (non-zero means it had a problem)